# General question about authentication in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I develop a SharePoint Online Provider hosted add-in.

My question is, does SharePoint Online use the Azure AD to authenticate the Users, Or is there any extra configuration neccessary for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SharePoint Online uses Azure AD (or the Azure ACS to be precise) for authenticating users (if no ADFS is put in place for trusting your on-premises AD to authenticate users that are synchronized from the same, but you will still be able to use authentication provided for Azure ACS, like [ADAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), to authenticate users via Azure ACS in this scenario).

Andrew Connell has a great article about it [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/understanding-access-tokens-in-the-azure-ad-office-365-api-authentication-dance)